# RhinoMocks.GenerateMock with generic type, GetGenericArguments is empty

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, rhino-mocks

Can anyone shed any light on how I can achieve this with RhinoMocks? I want to create a mock of a generic type (with two TypeParams) and in the code-under test I am calling GetType().GetGenericArguments(), expecting two Types.

e.g. I expect the following test to pass, but it fails:

```
    [Test]  
    public void Test()
    {
        // Mocking IDictionary<THash, T> fails, but new Dictionary<THash, T> passes
        var myMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDictionary<int, float>>();
        var args = myMock.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
        Assert.That(args, Is.EquivalentTo(new Type[] {typeof(int), typeof(float)}));
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that your *mock* will declare generic parameters for which you can obtain the arguments?  (it's a dynamically generated type that *implements* that dictionary interface; this generated type presumably declares no type parameters at all, nor should it)

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do something equivelent to `myMock.Object.GetType()...` ?

Comment: @KirkWoll because the return type of MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDictionary<int, float>> is IDictionary<int, float>. The proxy object implements an interface with generic parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the generic arguments for a type that declares none.  What you want is to get it from the *interface* that it implements.  This is just a crude example, but it should illustrate the idea for a solution:

```
myMock.GetType().GetInterfaces()
    .Single(x => x.Name.Contains("IDictionary")).GetGenericArguments();
```

Here we're looking for the interface implemented by the mock with the name `IDictionary` (probably better would be to compare using `.GetGenericTypeDefinition` against `typeof(IDictionary<,>)`) and grabbing the generic arguments from it.

For completeness, here's a more robust (and less stringy) solution (though harder to read):

```
myMock.GetType().GetInterfaces()
    .Single(x => x.IsGenericType && 
                 x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
    .GetGenericArguments();
```

Comment: I half figured it out from your comment above, but was searching for good syntax to dig into the inheritance tree. So, that's precisely what I was looking for, thanks :-)